# Inserting UITableViewCell Refuses to Occur on Cell Selection

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I've got a pretty specific issue I just cannot figure out. I've been trying to create my own iteration of Apple's [DateCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008866) project. One problem: I can't figure out why the DatePickerCell is not being inserted when a tap the cell at the section 1, row 0. An error is outputted, and I've tried to follow it, but I truly just cannot figure it out. The app crashes on the `tableview.insertRowsAtIndexPaths()` method.

Here's the View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class AddAssignmentViewController: UITableViewController {

    let cellTitles: [String] = ["Title", "Due Date", "Teacher"]
    var showDatePickerCell: Bool = false
    var showPickerCell: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource Implementation

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath {
        case NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 1):
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DatePickerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DatePickerCell
            return cell
        case NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 2):
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PickerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PickerCell
            return cell
        default:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
            cell.textLabel!.text = cellTitles[indexPath.section]
            return cell
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        switch indexPath {
        case NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 1):
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 1)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 2):
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 2)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if showDatePickerCell && section == 1 {
            return 2
        } else if showPickerCell && section == 2 {
            return 2
        }

        return 1
    }

    // MARK: - UIViewController Implementation (ViewController Life Cycle)

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    }

}
```

And the error when tapping on the cell at section 1, row 0:

```
2015-04-19 16:52:12.617 myHomework[6287:387908] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44/UITableView.m:1406
2015-04-19 16:52:12.620 myHomework[6287:387908] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 1 into section 1, but there are only 1 rows in section 1 after the update'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103516c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105081bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103516aca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001039b398f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000103e915c8 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 6907
    5   myHomework                          0x0000000102f175e0 _TFC10myHomework27AddAssignmentViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView23didSelectRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_T_ + 672
    6   myHomework                          0x0000000102f1790f _TToFC10myHomework27AddAssignmentViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView23didSelectRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_T_ + 79
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000103ea6dc9 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1293
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000103ea6f0a -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 219
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000103dd962c _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 314
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000103dd94a6 _afterCACommitHandler + 533
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103449ca7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103449c00 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010343fa33 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010343f366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001074fda3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000103db5900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    17  myHomework                          0x0000000102f0d837 main + 135
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001057d9145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `numberOfRowsInSection` method is only returning a count of 1 each time. Right now, it will return 2 if `showPickerCell` or `showDatePickerCell` are true, but they are always set to `false`. When `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` is called, it expects to ask the data source for a row count afterwards and get a value equal to the number of actual rows in the table view.

To fix the issue, you would want to set either of those properties to `true` inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` before inserting rows into the table view.